# how to call parameterized function in config .js file at feature file using karate framework?

Tags: karate

I need to pass response value from feature file  to javascript function which is defined at config.js file for some computation purposes .
Please help on how to call function which is present at config.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First refer to this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#javascript-functions

Just keep the JS as a `*.js` file and re-use it from any feature or the `karate-config.js`. Note that `karate.call()` is possible from JS, including `karate-config.js` and you can even call a feature file, not just JS.

Maybe you should also look at the example for [`karate.callSingle()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object) which is new in 0.7.0. As of the time of this post, version 0.7.0.RC5 is available to test.